# How to increment a state in React?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am learning React and have been given a simple challenge: to make a counter increment when a button is clicked.

The problem is my component seems to treat the numbers as strings and concatenates them, not increments them. Eg, if my starting number is 2 and I click 'Add 1' I get '21' instead of the expected result, '3'.

I tried to Google a way to mark them as integers, but had no luck.

My code is:

```
 var CountComponent = React.createClass({

    resetCount: function() {  
        this.setState({  
            count: '0'
        })
    },

    addOne: function() { 
        this.setState({
            count: this.state.count + 1
        })
    },

    getInitialState: function() { 
        return {
            count: '0'
        }
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Count {this.state.count}</h1>
                <button onClick={this.addOne}>Add 1</button>
                <button onClick={this.resetCount}>Reset</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <CountComponent />,
    document.getElementById('app') 
);
```

Would anyone know where I've gone wrong here?

Weirdly enough, I did find an example doing something very similar, but it seems to work https://codepen.io/ajcbrown820/pen/eZdWaj. I can't see the differences to mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because initially you defined the value of `count` **as string not integer**. When using `+` with string it will concatenate the values.

Use this:

```
getInitialState: function() { 
    return {
        count: 0
    }
},

resetCount: function() {  
    this.setState({  
        count: 0
    })
},
```

Check this snippet:

```js
let count = '0';

count = count + 1;

console.log('count = ', count);
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use numbers instead of strings !

adding string to a number will result in concatenating them, but adding numbers to each other, will result in incrementing the number

```
  getInitialState: function() { 
      return {
          count: 0
      }
  },
  resetCount: function() {  
      this.setState({  
          count: 0
      })
  },
```

You can also do this, but its not the better solution in this example:

```
   addOne: function() { 
        this.setState({
            count: +this.state.count + 1
        })
    },
```

The + before `this.state.count` will turn it into a number before adding 1 to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your number does seem to be a string!

Try replacing `'0'` with `0` in your example and give it another shot :)

Answer (score 0):

Your count state is treated as a string because it is. Try setting your state to 0 instead of '0'.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined count as string in `getInitialState` and `resetCount` *members*. Javascript + operator does the rest (that is string concatenation)
Try to initialize count as count: 0 (without apos) in the above functions ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, remove single quotes for 0. Quotes considered it as a string, not an integer.

```
resetCount: function() {  
    this.setState({  
        count: 0
    })
},

addOne: function() { 
    this.setState({
        count: this.state.count + 1
    })
},

getInitialState: function() { 
    return {
        count: 0
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a number to a string. So that number will also be treated as string.

```
count: '0'
```

it should be

```
count: 0
```

Then it'll work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try, below corrected code of yours.

```
var CountComponent = React.createClass({

    resetCount: function() {  
        this.setState({  
            count: 0
        })
    },

    addOne: function() { 
        this.setState({
            count: this.state.count + 1
        })
    },

    getInitialState: function() { 
        return {
            count: 0
        }
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Count {this.state.count}</h1>
                <button onClick={this.addOne}>Add 1</button>
                <button onClick={this.resetCount}>Reset</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

React.render(
    <CountComponent />,
    document.getElementById('app') 
);
```